# Angular show DIV only on some conditions

Tags: angular, angular-ng-if

I have a header.component.html file (this is a shared component), in which I except other things added a DIV with a message. This should be shown only if showMsg property is true:

```
<div *ngIf="showMsg" >Some message</div>
```

In the header.ts file I defined the property

```
showMsg: boolean;
```

and in constructor default:  `this.showMsg= false;`

This works fine, meaning if I set this.showMsg to true here, the message shows and vice versa.

But as this is a shared component, and it is included into `main.html` component via:

```
  <app-header></app-header>
```

and the data from backend, on which the showMsg should depend are only in **main.ts** component.

Only thing I need, let's say `this.Year` is a property from backend - and all I want is if the Year is 2021, then set `showMsg` to true and show message, otherwise hide the message in that shared component.

The problem is, my solution doesn't work:

```
if (this.Year === '2021')
      {this.showMsg = true; console.log(this.showMsg);}
```

Better to say, the condition is OK, showMsg will be set to true, but the message in header.html is not showing. Seems it ignores showMsg from main.ts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`@Input`](https://angular.io/guide/inputs-outputs#sending-data-to-a-child-component) property in the child component to set it's value from the parent component.

Child component controller

```js
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({...})
export class SharedComponent {
  @Input() showMsg: boolean = false;  // <-- default when `[showMsg]` is not bound in parent
  ...
}
```

Parent component controller

```js
showMsg: boolean = false;

someMethod() {
  this.someService.get('year').subscribe({
    next: (Year: any) => {
      this.showMsg = Year === '2021';
      ...
    },
    error: (error: any) => { }
  });
}
```

Parent component template

```html
<app-header [showMsg]="showMsg"></app-header>
```

Comment: Thank you, this way it works and makes sense for me!

Answer (score 1):

You can pass `showMsg` as input into your shared component like this

`<app-header [showMsg]="showMsg"></app-header>`

In your header.component.ts just add

```
@Input showMsg: boolean = false;
```

check https://angular.io/guide/inputs-outputs for more info